# How to properly count rows from mysql using python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to get rows quantity from query using python to mysql. I've been using `rowcount` but returned value is always 0.

```
def getLastData(md5TwitterDate):
    conectar = connection()
    try:
        cursor = conectar.cursor()
        query = "SELECT fecha,numeroreporte,internoid FROM jsywe_ncnsismos_sismosigp WHERE internoid = '%s' and published=1"
        cursor.execute(query, md5TwitterDate)
        lastEvent = cursor.fetchall()
        rowsa = cursor.rowcount
    except Error as ex:
        print("Error to get data: ", ex)
    finally:
        if conectar.is_connected():
            conectar.close()
    #return False if rowsa> 0 else True
    return rowsa
```

Also tried this way setting a variable to cursor.execute but in this case always get `none`

```
def getLastData(md5TwitterDate):
    conectar = connection()
    try:
        cursor = conectar.cursor()
        query = "SELECT fecha,numeroreporte,internoid FROM jsywe_ncnsismos_sismosigp WHERE internoid = '%s' and published=1"
        rowsa = cursor.execute(query, md5TwitterDate)
        lastEvent = cursor.fetchall()
    except Error as ex:
        print("Error to get data: ", ex)
    finally:
        if conectar.is_connected():
            conectar.close()
    #return False if filas > 0 else True
    return rowsa
```

Tested query on database and it works, it returns 1 row

Comment: does `len(lastEvent)` not do what you want?

Comment: @AndrejPrsa i think lastEvent gets [fecha,numeroreporte,internoid] so query will return 3 objects inside this array

Comment: That might depend on the backend? For mariadb, I use `dbc = db.cursor(dictionary=True)` and it returns a list of dicts, so `len()` will give me the number of queries records.

Comment: changed my query to get rows affected `SELECT COUNT(*) from......` thats how i could solve it